# Flex 3 - how to select the first item in a List using code?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I have a regular  control in my code with several items.

```
<mx:List id="myList">
    <mx:String>Item 1</mx:String>
    <mx:String>Item 2</mx:String>
</mx:List>
```

I have some other code which runs and populates the list. How do I select the first item in the newly populated list using code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be `myList.selectedItem`, if you have a reference to the object you would like to select, or `myList.selectedIndex`, if you have an index into the data source. Both properties are inherited from the ListBase class. They're documented in the ActionScript 3.0 Language Reference.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the getItemAt method of the List's dataProvider like this...   myList.dataProvider.getItemAt(0).